# How can i implement RTL for Yaxis in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js, right-to-left

Currently i am working on a website where i have to align the text RTL on label and tooltip because its Arabic.

I have read doc and searched alot but unable to understand why RTL is not working for tooltip and label

Check screenshots:
Label: https://prnt.sc/q95lf8
Tooltip: https://prnt.sc/q95mbz

This is my code below:

```
config.options.scales.xAxes =[ {
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: utils.getTranslations('average_complaints_for_1000', 'statistics'),
                            fontStyle: 'bold',
                            fontSize: (window.innerWidth<400)? 13 : 20,
                            align   : 'right',
                        },
                    }];     
                config.options.scales.yAxes[0].display=true;
                config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks={
                    fontSize: (window.innerWidth<400)? 13 :14 ,
                    fontFamily:'DroidKufi-Regular',
                };

                config.options.tooltips.enabled = true;

            this.generate_chart({
                container: '#bank_rate_of_complaints--section-1',
                canvas_id: 'bank_rate_of_complaints_canvas_1',
                chart_config: config,
                canvas_height: (data_set.labels.length < 6)? 70 : (data_set.labels > 5 && data_set.labels.length< 10 )? 190 : 300
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rtl and other settings in tooltips like below:

```
options = {
tooltips: {
  rtl: true,
  bodyFontSize: 10,
  titleFontSize: 11,
}}
```

I've used it for Persian Charts and worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the position option of y-axis:

```
let isRightToLeft = true;
chart.options = {
      scales: {
        y: {
          position: isRightToLeft ? 'right' : 'left',
        }
      }
    };
```